# How can I move my arm between two points using moveit commandator

Tags: ros, moveit, moveit-commander, moveit-tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am created a moveit plugin for my 6DOF arm.And I am trying to move my arm through a line. And I have two end co-ordinates of a line say (x1,y1,z1) and (x2, y2, z2) .

I can able to move to a random pose using

```
from moveit_commander import MoveGroupCommander

#if name == '__main__':
group = MoveGroupCommander("arm")

# move to a random target
group.clear_pose_targets()
group.go()
```

But I am not found a function that helps me to plan between two points.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/95806/how-can-i-move-my-arm-between-two-points-using-moveit-commandator/) by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 313 on 2013-10-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_commander/blob/hydro-devel/src/moveit_commander/move_group.py) is the code defining the MoveGroupCommander class
2. I'd recommend playing around with this (and any python code that you want to explore) in a REPL that has autocomplete (ipython is good). From there, you can see what functions exist for group by typing `group.`-[tab] , and what their arguments are by typing `group.set_pose_target(`-[tab].
3. To answer your direct question, this should work:

   group.set_position_target([x, y, z])
   group.go()

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on 2013-10-29**:
Thanks lindzey

**Comment by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on 2013-10-30**:
hi lindzy .. I can able to set the target. But how can I know which is the origin (0,0,0)